# Why do I get SQLCODE -206 when I run a query to calculate median value of a column?

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying to find median of the field "bal" based on "key" in DB2. I get this error when I execute this code "Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, SQLERRMC=KEY, DRIVER=3.66.46, SQLState:  42703).

Appreciate your comments !!

```
        SELECT
           key,
           AVG(bal)
        FROM
        (
           SELECT
              key,
              bal,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                 PARTITION BY key 
                 ORDER BY bal ASC) AS RowAsc,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                 PARTITION BY key 
                 ORDER BY bal DESC) AS RowDesc
           FROM tab1
        ) x
        WHERE 
           RowAsc IN (RowDesc, RowDesc - 1, RowDesc + 1)
        GROUP BY key
        ORDER BY key;
```

Comment: `key` is a SQL keyword, so it is probably reserved.  You can escape it.  Better yet, change the column name.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Thanks, even after changing it, it does not work

Comment: If you took time to check the manual, you'd learn that SQLCODE -206 tells you there is no column "KEY" in your table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that every reference to `key` becomes `"key"`

```
SELECT
      "key"
    , AVG(bal)
FROM (
      SELECT
            "key"
          , bal
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "key"
                               ORDER BY bal ASC)  AS rowasc
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "key"
                               ORDER BY bal DESC) AS rowdesc
      FROM tab1
) x
WHERE RowAsc IN (RowDesc, RowDesc - 1, RowDesc + 1)
GROUP BY
      "key"
ORDER BY
      "key"
;
```

Comment: Why do you think this column has been created in lowercase, unlike others?

Comment: Great question. I don't know if the column name is in either upper or lower case,  but it does need quoting because it is a resereved word. If lowercase does not work try uppercase but retain the quotes. If still having issues look at the definition of the table to get the actual case used for that column.